# Pass each data to function from multiple numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have [*,4] shape of np.array and want to path the each element to function.

So I am trying to use np.where but in vain.

My idea is not good? I am appreciate if some one would give me the ihnt.

```
items = np.array([
            ["book","book","car","car"],
            ["car","desk","book","car"],
)

result = np.where(itemToLit(items)) // ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()


def itemToList(item):
   if item == "book":
      return np.array([1,0])
   if item == "car":
      return np.array([0,1])
   if item == "desk":
      return np.array([1,1])
```

The result I want to get is like this

```
np.array([
  [[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]]
  [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,1]]
])
```

Comment: So what you mean is that `[1, 0]` if there is a `"book"`, and if there is also a `"car"` it would be `[1,1]`?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the each word to the numpy list

Comment: Done please check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for loop:

```
items = np.array([
            ["book","book","car","car"],
            ["car","desk","book","car"]])
a = []
for i in items:
    a += [[]]
    for x in i:
        a[-1] += [[]]
        if x == "book":
            a[-1][-1].extend([1, 0])
        if x == "car":
            a[-1][-1].extend([0, 1])
        if x == "desk":
            a[-1][-1].extend([1, 1])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you it works and solve my quesion `a[-1]` is the great hint for this problem.

Comment: @whitebear Your welcome :-) `a[-1]` gets the last value of the list :-)